# Unexpected EOF while parsing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
import time

print ('WELCOME TO MYSTREY MADNESS warning this is my first game their will be bugs')
time.sleep (2)
print ('you will be asked to pick a route and the game will pick a random outcome')
time.sleep (2)
print ('pick one of the two options that will appear in a moment type 1 or 2 next to the one that you wnat to pick')
time.sleep (2)
guess_1 = int(input('you are at the beach you are bored type 1 to go to the rock pools type 2 to go to the cave')
    if guess_1 == 1
        ("you went to the rock pools what do you do now?")
    else guess_1 == 2,
        print('you go to the cave and look into the darkness what do you do now?'),
```

I have tried raw input on my only input but it was still giving me an error message.

Comment: You have a lot of basic errors with your syntax. You might want to reread the tutorial you're going through.

Answer (score 1):

As Morgan said, there are some syntax errors on your code. You should close some parenthesis and remove the comas at the end of some lines.
This code should work well:

```
import random
import time

print ('WELCOME TO MYSTREY MADNESS warning this is my first game their will be bugs')
time.sleep (2)
print ('you will be asked to pick a route and the game will pick a random outcome')
time.sleep (2)
print ('pick one of the two options that will appear in a moment type 1 or 2 next to the one that you wnat to pick')
time.sleep (2)
guess_1 = int(input('you are at the beach you are bored type 1 to go to the rock pools type 2 to go to the cave'))
if (guess_1 == 1):
    print("you went to the rock pools what do you do now?")
elif (guess_1 == 2):
    print('you go to the cave and look into the darkness what do you do now?')
```

Comment: Please remove the parentheses in `if (guess_1 == 1):`. They are superfluous. `if guess_1 == 1:` is enough.